# NGINX request forwarding with dollar sign in URL

Tags: nginx

I want to setup NGINX so that all requests of the form:

```
example.com/$
example.com/$/
example.com/$/a
example.com/$/a/
example.com/$/a/b/
```

are forwarded to one upstream server and everything else is forwarded to another upstream server but cannot get it to work. I am trying following config:

```
location / {
// server 1
}

location ~ ^/\$/(.*)$ {
// server 2
}
```

The `~` is for regex match. I have used `\$` to escape `$` sign. The `/.*` is supposed to match paths of the form I have listed above.

but when I make requests to `example.com/$` I get back a bad request from NGINX. Does anyone know how to do this? Also I need to handle encoded URIs:

```
> encodeURIComponent('$')
'%24'
```

so if the URI uses `%24` instead of `$`, it should be handled properly. Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that.  Dollar sign is a reserved character in HTTP URLs.  It will work in many contexts, but it's just a bad idea.

Comment: ... [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for reference

Answer (score -1):

This works with `/%24` and `/$`

```
  location ^~ /$ { 
  }
```